# Java RegEx: Very Specific Match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a hyphen in all situations except when it is preceded by whitespace and proceeded by non-whitespace.

```
x-y   //match
x - y //match
x- y  //match
x -y  //not match
```

I want the regex to determine a match based on the above requirements but only capture the negative sign. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Edited for accuracy.

Comment: It seems you're example and requirement don't match. Could you be more accurate?

Comment: You're right Steinar. I fixed up the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible using a negative lookbehind and a positive lookahead assertion ([docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
(?<!\s)-|-(?=\s)
```

Which says: Match any hyphen either (not preceded by whitespace) or (proceeded by whitespace). This is the same as saying "*not* (preceded by whitespace) and (proceeded by non-whitespace)", according to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Sorry for the ambiguity in the question too; I changed it so my description matches my examples now.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ multiple alternatives, one for each case:

```java
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "  (?<=\\S)-(?=\\S)  # x-y   //match\n" +
    "| (?<=\\s)-(?=\\s)  # x - y //match\n" +
    "| (?<=\\S)-(?=\\s)  # x- y  //match", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

This logic could probably be shortened (at the expense of some readability).